# Python: lxml findall returning object, not value inside element text

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I have written the following python code to parse a XML file with lxml. I am confused why it is returning a memory address but not the actual output `height` in this case.

```
import pdb
from pprint import pprint
from lxml import etree

def main():
    parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata = False)
    tree = etree.parse("xml.xml", parser)
    string =  etree.tostring(tree.getroot())
    content = etree.fromstring(string)
    bodies = content.findall('Body')
    all_data = []
    for body in bodies:
        row  = {}
        height = body.findall('height')

        row['height'] = height
        all_data.append(row)
    print all_data
    pdb.set_trace()
```

The output that I got is:

```
[{'height': [<Element height at 0x11ac80830>]}]
```

whereas I expect a height of `178`.

The data within the xml file is:

```
<Bodies>
  <Body>
    <name><![CDATA[abc]]></name>
       <body_name><![CDATA[asdjakhdas da sdasda sd]]></body_name>
       <final_height><![CDATA[199]]></final_height>
       <categories><![CDATA[a / b / c]]></categories>
       <hand><![CDATA[asdkj]]></hand>
        <height>178</height>
  </Body>
<Bodies>
```

Comment: use `etree.tostring` to print lxml elements. your data structure is heavily nested, so you'll need to do some digging into it, instead of passing the whole `all_data` list to it.

Comment: So what's the output that you *do* want? You're putting the element, not a string serializing the element and its subtree, into that variable... so of course what you get follows from that.

Comment: The output that I want is `178`.

Comment: BTW, showing object IDs (the "memory address" you referred to) is how *all* objects in Python without `__repr__` methods are serialized, so whenever you see one, you know that your value is an object instance. Which should be a pretty good clue to look into how to get the value you want out of your object.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to put the height *element* into your variable, but instead the text field it contains:

```
height = body.find('height')
row['height'] = float(height.text) if height else None
```

Note the use of `find` as opposed to `findall` -- `findall` returns a list, whereas it sounds like you're expecting only a single value (and have no need to recurse).